# Dynamically created Iframe not accessible

Tags: jquery, iframe

I'm implementing an an ajax image upload feature which uses an iframe.
I've searched SO and found similar questions but I've tried them and they haven't worked for me.
My ajax image upload works as follows:

- User clicks "add image" button, which dynamically creates a new dialog box `$('#imgdialog')`. This dialog box is just a div that contains a dynamically-created form, `$('#imgform')` and an iframe, `$('#upload_target')`.
- The form allows the user to choose a file, which *should* show up in the iframe, via ajax uplaod.

But this doesn't happen. I'm following this tutorial: http://www.ajaxf1.com/tutorial/ajax-file-upload-tutorial.html

The main difference between my implementation and the one in the tutorial is that in my implementation, the form and iframe are not there to begin with when the page loads, they are created on the fly when the user clicks a button.

I know my PHP code is working fine because when I use FireBug I can see the required POST and RESPONSE. But the Iframe doesn't get populated, although in FireBug I can see it exists in the HTML, except it's empty.

The code that creates the dynamic form and iframe is:

```
    imgform = document.createElement('form');
    imgform.id = 'imgform';
    imgform.method='post';
    imgform.enctype='multipart/form-data';
    imgform.action ='upload_1.php';
    imgform.target = 'upload_target';
    imgform.onsubmit='showUploadedItem();';
    $('#imgform').append("Select image:<br /><input type='file' id='imgfile' />");
    $('#imgdialog').append("<iframe id='upload_target' name='upload_target' style='border:1px solid gray;' src='#'></iframe>");

    $('#upload_target').bind('load', function() { // doesn't work with .live either
         $(this).contents().find("body").html('greetings from the iframe !');
         alert("loaded");
    });
```

In `$('#imgform')`'s, onSubmit function, I also include the following line:

```
    if($('#upload_target').length > 0){ alert("it's there"); } else {alert ("not there"); }
```

And I got "not there".

How can I access the iframe?

Comment: I've tried both, no difference.

Comment: Checkout my answer, does that fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the issue is your setting the response target before the iframe exists? I've definitely binded listeners to these kinds of events to iframes (i think even dynamically created ones). There is some awkwardness to it though - might've required a really small plugin in jQuery depending on what kind of loading-ish event you wanted.

Also, where is the #imgdialog div being dynamically created? Not in the code here. Perhaps you meant to give  an id of imgdialog instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document.body).on('DOMNodeInserted', 'iframe', function(e) {
    console.log('inserted', e);
});

var frame = document.createElement('iframe');
$(document.body).append(frame);
```

or define function and call it from iframe content directly